# Switching which site is primary for a user

Tags: support, chat, user-accounts, sister-site

My "primary" site is English.SE: that's what's listed as the "parent user" of https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/5926/msh210, for example. Is there a way to change that, so my account on a different SE is primary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my profile I can see a [change] link right next to `parent user  Stack Overflow M'vy`

A text box will pop asking you to type the site you want to put. Auto-completion is on.

Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Sheesh: I'm a moron. Yes, it is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Have fun.