# How to change my chat username?

Tags: support, chat, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [switching which site is primary for a user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92440/switching-which-site-is-primary-for-a-user)

How can I change my username in Chat?

I'd like to participate in the chat for a site where I go by *Tim*, but the chat insists on calling my by my first and last name (which is also what my network profile does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the parent user of your chat account.

[image: below the about section]

I don't believe it is possible to have different names for different rooms on the same chat site.