# Add the ability to change username for per-site chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

It seems that all chat rooms use the same user as the "primary user" for all rooms ([see reference here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92591/155556)).

Can we make it so that it does not do that?

Can we make it so that I can use my SciFi username for when I chat on Mos Eisley for example and my Stack Overflow username for when I chat there or just the ability to be able to pick a "user" to use for that chatroom?

It gets hard to identify users from chat when they post on the site if they have a different name in the chatroom then on the actual site.
[It even comes as a suprise to some people!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6618195#6618195)

Comment: I'd rather force users to have the same name on chat and sites. *[evil grin face](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7160/6562466345_44a2812a69_z.jpg)*

Comment: @Alenanno: That could only be done if there was an association between the individual site user accounts and the chat site user accounts. As it stands now, you have to pick one account from one SE site as the master account for *all* chat rooms.  Unless you are suggesting that users should use the same name *everywhere.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was kind of provoking, not really a well-thought comment. :P